# using JDBC preparedStatement in a batch

Tags: java, jdbc, batch-file, prepared-statement

Im using `Statement`s batchs to query my data base. 
Iv'e done some research now and i want to rewrite my application to use `preparedStatement` instead but i'm having hard time to figure out how to add queries to a `preparedStatement` batch.

This is what i'm doing now:

```
private void addToBatch(String sql) throws SQLException{
sttmnt.addBatch(sql);
batchSize++;
if (batchSize == elementsPerExecute){
    executeBatches();
}
}
```

where `sttmnt` is a class member of type `Statement`.

What i want to do is to use the `preparedStatement`'s `setString(int, String)` method to set some dynamic data and then add it to the batch.

Unfortunately, i don't fully understand how it works, and how i can use `setString(int, String)` to a specific sql in the batch OR create a new `preparedStatemnt` for every sql i have and then join them all to one batch.

is it possible to do that? or am i really missing something in my understanding of `preparedStatement`?

Comment: If you have found an answer accept the one that has helepd you the msot so others can learn as well

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Read the [section 6.1.2 of this document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame6.html) for examples. Basically you use the same statement object and invoke the batch method after all the placeholders are set. [Another IBM DB2 example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/tjvbtupd.htm) which should work for any JDBC implementation. From the second site:

```
try {
  connection con.setAutoCommit(false);        
  PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(    
    "UPDATE DEPT SET MGRNO=? WHERE DEPTNO=?");
  prepStmt.setString(1,mgrnum1);            
  prepStmt.setString(2,deptnum1);
  prepStmt.addBatch();                      

  prepStmt.setString(1,mgrnum2);                        
  prepStmt.setString(2,deptnum2);
  prepStmt.addBatch();
  int [] numUpdates=prepStmt.executeBatch();
  for (int i=0; i < numUpdates.length; i++) {
    if (numUpdates[i] == -2)
      System.out.println("Execution " + i + 
        ": unknown number of rows updated");
    else
      System.out.println("Execution " + i + 
        "successful: " + numUpdates[i] + " rows updated");
  }
  con.commit();
} catch(BatchUpdateException b) {
  // process BatchUpdateException
}
```

Comment: but what if i want the statements to be different, lets say an INSERT, and then several updates? can i do that?

Comment: AFAIK, no. As you can see, `addBatch` is invoked on the `Statement` object and hence whatever statement holds would be added to batch. If you have statements of multiple types, it no longer is a batch; it kinda becomes a script.

Comment: `Statement` has a method `void addBatch(String sql)` that allows to assemble batches (which bight be regarded as scripts)

Answer (score 9):

With `PreparedStatement`'s you have wild cards in a way, for example

```
Sring query = "INSERT INTO users (id, user_name, password) VALUES(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.preparedStatement(query);
for(User user: userList){
    statement.setString(1, user.getId()); //1 is the first ? (1 based counting)
    statement.setString(2, user.getUserName());
    statement.setString(3, user.getPassword()); 
    statement.addBatch();
}
```

This will create 1 `PreparedStatement` with that query shown above.You can loop through list when you want to insert or whatever you intentions are. When you want to execute you,

```
statement.executeBatch();
statement.clearBatch(); //If you want to add more, 
//(so you don't do the same thing twice)
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm adding an extra answer here specifically for MySQL.

I found that the time to do a batch of inserts was similar to the length of time to do individual inserts, even with the single transaction around the batch.

I added the parameter `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to my jdbc url, and saw a dramatic improvement - in my case, a batch of 200 inserts went from 125 msec. without the parameter to about 10 to 15 msec. with the parameter.

See [MySQL and JDBC with rewriteBatchedStatements=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307760/mysql-and-jdbc-with-rewritebatchedstatements-true)