# Java - Having a huge ArrayList (1 million +), how to create a String of it in a acceptable amount of time?

Tags: java, mysql, csv, arraylist

as I mentioned, I have huge ArrayLists in this format:

```
List<List<String>> alist;
```

I get the Lists out of some .CSV wich I get over a extern databasesystem. (I wrote a Visual Objects script to export the data we need for some calculations)

After I have the .CSV, I load the content into my List like this:

```
String line;
       alist = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
       int i=0;
    // Datei laden, und anschließend die Zeilen der CSV in eine ArrayList speichern 

       try {             

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.replace(",", ".");
                if(line.endsWith(delimitter))
                    line = line + " ";
                alist.add(Arrays.asList(line.split(delimitter)));
                i++;
                if(i==10000000)
                    break;
            }       

        }
```

It takes me like ~15900 ms to store the Data in my ArrayList (~1,1 million rows and 11 columns). Pretty okay I guess.
Now, that I have the List in the format I need, I would like to create a Insert out of it, so we can import the data in our database.
I'm creating the insert like this:

```
public String getInsertString()
    {
        // Tabelle ergibt sich aus dem Dateinamen, ohne das .csv
        String insert="REPLACE INTO "+tablename + " (";

        // Spaltennamen aus Array auslesen, immer die erste Zeile des CSV
        for(int i=0; i< alist.get(0).size();i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
                insert = insert + alist.get(0).get(i).trim();
            else
                insert = insert + " ,"+ alist.get(0).get(i).trim();
        }
        insert= insert + ") \rVALUES";

        // Values der SPalten in den Insert schreiben + korreckte Syntax des Bfehels sicherstellen usw.
        for(int i=1;i < alist.size();i++) // Size nach "unten" in der 2D Liste
        {

            insert= insert +"(";
            for(int j=0; j < alist.get(0).size();j++) // Size nach "rechts" in der 2D Liste
            {
                // bei dem ersten ohne "," starten, damit die Syntax stimmt
                // Sollte der aktuelle Wert eine Zahl oder "null" sein, keine "'" setzen. Ansonsten "'" setzen fuer den Insert in die DB
                if(j==0)
                {           
                    if((StringUtils.isStrictlyNumeric(alist.get(i).get(j).trim())) || alist.get(i).get(j).trim().contains("null"))
                        insert = insert + alist.get(i).get(j).trim();
                    else 
                        insert = insert + "'" + alist.get(i).get(j).trim() + "'";
                }                   
                else
                {
                    if(((StringUtils.isStrictlyNumeric(alist.get(i).get(j).trim()))) || (alist.get(i).get(j).trim().contains("null")))
                        insert = insert +","+ alist.get(i).get(j).trim();
                    else 
                        insert = insert + ",'" + alist.get(i).get(j).trim() + "'";      
                }

            }
            if(i < alist.size()-1)
                insert= insert +"),";
            else 
                insert= insert +")";
            insert = insert +"\r";

        }

        //System.out.println(insert);
        return insert;

    }
```

Here I go over the whole List and add the values to a string so that I can use the string for a insert.
I use the filenames as table names and the first row of a file for the columns in the insert.
All other rows are the values.

After this step is done, I get a string like this
"REPLACE INTO tablename (column1,column2 ... columnx)
VALUES(value1, value2 ... valuex),
(value1, value2 ... valuex),
...."

Now I would excecute my InsertInDb class with that string and yeah, thats it.

But the second step takes way too much time. (I wait for like a hour now)
Is there a smarter way to do what I want to do?
(Insert all CSV automaticly in our Database)

Would a BigList maybe improve the speed? 
https://dzone.com/articles/biglist-scalable-high
(can't test it right now)

**Edit:**
What I did to solve the problem:

I created a class for my SQL statement -->

```
public class BuildInsert {


    private String insertString;

    public String getINSERTSTRING()
    {
        return insertString;
    }

    BuildInsert(String tablename, List<String> alist )
    {   
        int size = alist.size();

        this.insertString = "REPLACE INTO " + tablename + "(";

        // Insert "Header"
        for(int j=1; j <= size ;j++) 
        {
            if(j < size)
                this.insertString = this.insertString + alist.get(j-1)+",";
            else
                this.insertString = this.insertString + alist.get(j-1)+")\n";

        }

        this.insertString = this.insertString +"VALUES(";

        // Insert values
        for(int j=1; j <= size ;j++) 
        {
            if(j < size)
                this.insertString = this.insertString + "?,";
            else
                this.insertString = this.insertString + "?)";

        }
    }

}
```

and tock this String for a batch insert / prepared statement as Mike mentioned:

```
Connection con;
        Statement stmt;

        final int batchSize = 1000;
        int count = 0;

        int sizeH = alist.size();
        int sizeL = alist.get(0).size();

        try {

             // Connection oeffnen und prepared statment vorbereiten
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            ps = con.prepareStatement(insertString);

            stmt = con.createStatement();

          //< alist.size()
            for(int i=1;i < sizeH ;i++) // Size nach "unten" 
            {
                for(int j=0; j < sizeL;j++) // Size nach "rechts" 
                {
                    ps.setString(j+1, alist.get(i).get(j));
                }

                ps.addBatch();

                if(++count % batchSize == 0){
                    ps.executeBatch();
                    con.commit();
                }
            }    

            ps.executeBatch();
            con.commit();

        }
```

The insert is much faster now. (~230 sek for 1,1 mil rows)

Thank you guys ;-)

Comment: At least use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Take a look at this question about importing csv into mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table

Comment: To keep this logic of reading the file, I would use a PreparedStatement, this will be much faster to insert 1million of row. Execute the preparedStatement for each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Now, that I have the List in the format I need, I would like to create a Insert out of it, so we can import the data in our database.
```

Don't do that! Do a [JDBC batch insert](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/) instead. (See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) on how to do a PreparedStatement which will save you a lot of trouble on formatting the insert statements)

Comment: And will save the time of compiling a huge query, or a lot of small ones. This is the perfect cases for a PreparedStatement.

Comment: This sounds interesting, I will try it out.

Comment: Okay, this worked pretty well. Now I need like 230ish seconds for 1.1 million + rows

Comment: It will also stop SQL injection. Seems like this could be very vulnerable with so many iterations going on :D

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to load a CSV file into mysql you should use mysql tools. E.g. [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
 IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

If you still want to do it by yourself you should use [JDBC Batch Insert](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/javaentnut_2/index3.html?page=2). Also consider to use `PreparedStatement` with jdbc batch. See [using JDBC preparedStatement in a batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860691/using-jdbc-preparedstatement-in-a-batch)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer to your question: "the second step takes way too much time. (I wait for like a hour now) Is there a smarter way to do what I want to do? (Insert all CSV automaticly in our Database)"

**Fastest solution**

As stated on the MySQL Reference Manual ([Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-speed.html)) the fastest way is to use LOAD DATA INFILE.

**Java solution**

Although if you want to try also a Java solution you may reconsider your work. The insert produced by your code use the syntax with multiple VALUES (the recommended one) but it's too long:

```
    11*10^6 rows x 11 cols x 10B per col = 11^2*10^7 = approx. 1GB
```

So try to:

- set your own variable batch-size and create multiple insert statement with at most such number of multiple values
- check that the batch-size you choose is lower than  bulk_insert_buffer_size (see reference in the same link above)
- use PreparedStatement but instead of a string to execute you have to build a string (with ? in place of values) and an array of arguments (the values); [Java Tutorial JDBC Basics - Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- if you use a PreparedStatement then you can avoid to check if you are going to insert a number, a string or other (using `setObject` method) so you can avoid those redundant control about the content of the csv field (this is validation and you should move it on the parsing step)