# Use JFileChooser to select multiple files at once

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql, prepared-statement

I know we can enable multi-selection using `fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true)`. But I need a way to add all the selected 
files into the database.

I've tried using `getFilesSelected()` but the problem is that when I hit **enter**, only the first selected image is added to the database.

This is what I've tried,

```
fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new ImageFilter());
 if (fc.showOpenDialog(btnBrowse) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        textField.setEditable(true);
        img_name.setEditable(true);
        textField.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        img_name.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().substring(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("\\")+1)); 
        String ext = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().substring(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
        file_ext = ext.substring(ext.indexOf('.'),(ext.length()));



  String query = " insert into load_images(format,image_name,file_loc,photo,date_field) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
  preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

  preparedStmt.setString (1,file_ext);
  preparedStmt.setString (2,img_name.getText());
  preparedStmt.setString (3, textField.getText());

  File f=new File(textField.getText());
  int size=(int) f.length();
  FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);

  preparedStmt.setBinaryStream(4,fis,size);
  preparedStmt.setTimestamp(5, getCurrentTimeStamp());

  preparedStmt.execute();
```

Comment: This seems to have a lot less to do with Swing or `JFileChooser` than the DB, so you might try working it out in a command line app. first!

Comment: If you are loading it into mulriple rows then [upload all the rows using batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860691/using-jdbc-preparedstatement-in-a-batch) - Documentation: [`PreparedStatement.addBatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch()) and [`Statement.executeBatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch())

Comment: Tip: Add @MT0 (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I created a function to insert every single image into the database.

Here's the code:

```
            fc.setSelectedFile(null);
            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:/Users"));
            fc.setDialogTitle("File Browser");
            fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            fc.resetChoosableFileFilters();
            fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
            fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new ImageFilter());

            if (fc.showOpenDialog(btnBrowse) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                        {
                            inputFiles = fc.getSelectedFiles();

                            for (File f: inputFiles) 
                            {
                                path = f.getAbsolutePath();
                                imgName = f.getName();
                                textField.setEditable(true);
                                img_name.setEditable(true);
                                textField.setText(path);
                                img_name.setText(imgName);

                                file_ext = imgName.substring(imgName.indexOf('.'),(imgName.length()));

                                insert(file_ext,imgName,path);


                            }
                        }
```

Here's the function,

```
public void insert(String fileext, String imgNam, String url)
{   

    try 
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.180.86.139:1521:syndupgdb","fcrhost","FCRHOST");
        String query = " insert into load_images(format,image_name,file_loc,photo,date_field) values (?,?,?,?,?)";

              preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

              preparedStmt.setString (1,fileext);
              preparedStmt.setString (2,imgNam);
              preparedStmt.setString (3,url);


              File fil=new File(url);
              int size=(int) fil.length();
              FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fil);
              preparedStmt.setBinaryStream(4,fis,size);

              preparedStmt.setTimestamp(5, getCurrentTimeStamp());

           preparedStmt.execute();
           con.close();


        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Your data Has been Inserted","Result", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }

    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception:" + e1);
    }

}
```