# Batch processing using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, batch-processing

Am I right when I say that I can only use 1 string sql query for batch processing using `PreparedStatement` in Java?

For example, this is the batch I want to process using `PreparedStatement`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Customer VALUES(?,?,?,?)
INSERT INTO tbl_Order VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
```

Is there any way to process these statements as a batch? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using JDBC preparedStatement in a batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860691/using-jdbc-preparedstatement-in-a-batch)

Comment: You can't do both in the same batch. You can, however use two PreparedStatements in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You the following template:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;

ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tbl_Customer VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
while () { 
    ...
    ps.addBatch();
}
result = ps.executeBatch();
```

Comment: I want to insert into 2 different tables. Your code only help add many records into 1 single table.

Comment: use 1 function but call it twice with 2 SQLs

Comment: The point of using a batch is it can rollback when there's something wrong with a record. Thus, there's no record is inserted into database. If I use 2 SQLs, the other still is inserted into database, right?

Comment: @TeraMind Then you should use [transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) if you want to ensure both statements are successfully executed.

Comment: @Tera Mind. see Flown comment. if you didn't call commit yet and remain in same context rollback will rollback both batches