# Best way to insert list of entities in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a list of entities. What is the best way to save it? Currently, I am using a for loop, which is taking a log of time:

```
List <Customer> cust:

for (Customer c: cust) {
 custRepository. save(c) 
}
```

Comment: How custRepository looks like?

Comment: I need to create list of customers almost 100+ at a time.... Which contains basic details if the customer.. Almost 5 cols only

Comment: **How your `custRepository` class looks like?** If it extends/implements `CrudRepository` then you should have `saveAll` method...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "batch Insert" for processing amount of data
Example: [using JDBC preparedStatement in a batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860691/using-jdbc-preparedstatement-in-a-batch)