# Is it possible to use addBatch() for preparedStatements in the following way?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, statements

I have the following code.

```java
try {
    PreparedStatement preSt = null;
    try {
        preSt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into table values (?)");
        preSt.setBigDecimal(1, bdVal);
        preSt.addBatch();

        while (condition) {
            preSt.setBigDecimal(1, bdVal1);
            preSt.addBatch();
        }
        while (condtiton2) {
            preSt.setBigDecimal(1, bdVal2);
            preSt.addBatch();
        }

        preSt.executeBatch();

    }
}
```

I want to insert different values into the table based on the condition using prepared statements. Would the above solution work? Is there any documentation/examples available for the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using JDBC preparedStatement in a batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860691/using-jdbc-preparedstatement-in-a-batch)

Comment: Your solution will work. Also detailed manual https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-batch-processing

Comment: Why do you think this wouldn't work?