# SQL batch insert incorrectly flagging last element of list as duplicate key

Tags: java, sql-server, batch-processing

The table in M$ SQL Server 2019  15.0.4.4335.1

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id bigint IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
    , last_name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
    , first_name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
    , middle_name nvarchar(255)
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    , CONSTRAINT PK_FULL_NAME UNIQUE ( last_name, first_name, middle_name)
);
```

which corresponds with class Foo.

in Java 8 I read in a tab in a spreadsheet using Apache POI to populate a List<Foo> list_foo.
So far so good.

I then try to populate the table with the list using

```
try {
    String sqlCmd = "INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt = connect.prepareStatement( sqlCmd);
    ListIterator<Foo> li = list_foo.listIterator();
    while( li.hasNext()) {
        Foo obj = li.next();
        stmt.setString( 1, obj.getLastName());
        stmt.setString( 2, obj.getFirstName());
        stmt.setString( 3, obj.getMiddleName());
        stmt.addBatch();
    }
    int[] insr_cnt = stmt.executeBatch()
    connect.commit();
    System.out.println( "rows inserted: " + insr_cnt);
} catch ( java.sql.BatchUpdateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();            // this gets thrown, see below
} catch ( SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch ( Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

this throws a:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint PK_FULL_NAME UNIQUE . Cannot insert duplicate key ( 'Williams','Wendy','Ophelia' ).

Sounds pretty straight-forward. But a visual inspection of the tab shows 1) this is indeed a unique triplet and 2) the last row in the tab.

Just for fun I manually moved this row somewhere in the middle of the tab so 'Pierce','Benjamen','Franklin'  became the last row. Executing the code threw same exact error but with PBF as the duplicate.

So it seems there's some subtlety with the code not liking the last row of the tab / last element of list_foo.

Anyone run into this before? And if so what's the solution?

Comment: What is "a modern version of SQL Server."? Give us the exact version e.g. `select @@version.`

Comment: Sounds more like your code is inserting the first or last row twice...

Comment: What happens if you define, populate, execute, and discard your `PreparedStatement stmt` object entirely within the loop? I'm wondering if the current code is somehow adding multiple INSERTS all referencing the same three parameters, and only the last three values are be applied - multiple times across all of the INSERTS. This might be executing the equivalent of `INSERT INTO foo VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3); GO; INSERT INTO foo VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3); GO; ...`, where the values `@p1`, `@p2`, and `@p3` have the last assigned values (last row from your input data) and don't change.

Comment: *Follow-up on my earlier comment:* A google search of [code samples](https://www.google.com/search?q=preparedStatement+setString+addBatch+executeBatch) and the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860691/) show multiple code snippets that seem to show that your posted code is correct. My earlier thoughts might be a dead end.  It still seems like something is causing an extra execution.

Comment: You might need some debugging. Print and check the value of `list_foo.Length` and the assigned parameter values set inside each loop iteration. Perhaps your source data parser is trying to process an empty line past the end of your data and somehow duplicating the last successfully-parsed values.

Comment: "a visual inspection of the tab shows 1) this is indeed a unique triplet" I don't know what a 'tab' is, but have you checked that `list_foo` contains what you expect, by logging its contents or using the debugger?

Comment: We really need to see more code, i.e. a "reproducible example". Definitely should be checking what's in `list_foo`. Also - be very very careful about visual inspections!! This has bitten me many times. And futhermore, should be checking what's in the database too. Your code "should" ! error if the name is already in the database - who knows, that could be data already present, or listed on other tabs too.

Comment: SQL version 15.0.1

Comment: Design comment: Never use a full name as a unique key, your system will break the moment two different people with the exact same name appear in your input.

Comment: SQL version 15.0.1 --- "tab" , another word for a "sheet" in an *xcel spreadsheet *.xslx file -- I added a step of using list_foo to populate a Set<org.javatuples.Quartet> and discovered the count of the set was short of the list count by a dozen, proving the list was not unique. Then a Map<Quartet,Integer> yielded which Quartets had a count > 1. Which made deleting the dupes from the tab easy, which allowed table to be populated. Problem solved. (Re)learned Lesson - Never Trust Input.   Thanks to all who responded... CASE CLOSED

Comment: I would suggest that instead of just deduping the data, you investigate where the duplicate rows came from. Was bad or unexpected data in original input causing duplication of prior rows? Does the input legitimately have duplicate last/first/middle name combinations, such as a common name or father/son both part of the data? Many medical applications use name plus date-of-birth to look up patients, and even then, they still need to deal with duplicates.

Comment: Your code is missing a semicolon on stmt.executeBatch() meaning you have probably anonymized too much and don't show full code which is an automatic close vote for me